# Configure email delivery in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am doing send email in laravel.
I configured gmail sending and it sent email successfully.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Now i send my company email: `reply@jct.com`

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.jtc.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=reply@jct.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=reply@jct.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But I can't send email. It reports an error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
> "reply@jct.com" using 2 possible authenticators.
> Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an
> empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code
> 250 but got an empty response.

Please show me where did I go wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have smtp.reply@jct.com set as MAIL_HOST before this config?  try running php artisan config:cache to make sure the newest config is loaded.

Comment: `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.reply@jct.com'),`  I config/email.php .I set it like that. And run config:cache but it still doesn't work

Comment: looks like your .env is ignored. the default value 'smtp.reply@jct.com' is not correct, you should change that to smtp.jtc.com

Comment: I did it the same way, but it still doesn't work :)) `Connection could not be established with host smtp.jtc.com :stream_socket_client()`

Comment: Maybe its getting blocked by the firewall